ERROR 1044 (42000) while updating mysql database
I'm trying to send a json file to my MySQL database from bash script. As far as I know the syntax for json file part is correct but there is a strange error that I cant understand.
I run the following code:

EXPORT_DIR="sunum"

file_name="105069_2024-03-19_20:09:06.mp4"

IFS='.'
read -ra ADDR <<< ${file_name}
report_filename=${ADDR[0]}".json"
report_dir="${EXPORT_DIR}/${report_filename}"
echo "${report_dir}"
    
VAR=$(cat "${report_dir}")
    
echo "${VAR}"

echo "${file_name}"

mysql --user="sql_vestelrecog_" --password="H76X53WN2ZaaJY84" --database="sql_vestelrecog_" \
--port="3306" --execute="UPDATE media SET rapor = "${VAR}" WHERE file_name = "${file_name}"" 


and get the following error:
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'sql_vestelrecog_'@'localhost' to database 'mp4'
My database name sql_vestelrecog_ and its already defined, how come the the extension of the filename (mp4) becomes the database name and I get this connection error??

Please add a valid shebang (#!/bin/bash) to your script, then paste it at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement all the recommendations made there.

Thank you, yes I added #!/bin/bash right now and updated the suggestions but its only about the double quotes around VAR variable and doesn't really change anything..

You need quotes around ${VAR} and ${file_name} so they will be treated as strings, not database, table, and column names.

There's also no need to end the double-quoted strings when substituting variables into the string. You'll get incorrect results if the variable contains whitespace.

You should put the variables in single quotes, assuming they contain strings ($file_name is obviously a string).
mysql --user="sql_vestelrecog_" --password="H76X53WN2ZaaJY84" --database="sql_vestelrecog_" \
--port="3306" --execute="UPDATE media SET rapor = '${VAR}' WHERE file_name = '${file_name}'" 

Note that substituting variables direclty into SQL leaves you open to SQL injection. It would be better if you could use a programming language that supports prepared statements, such as PHP or Python, rather than doing the query from bash.

that one worked thanks!!
